# Removing duplicate entries with Grafana and Loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I am using Grafana to visualize metrics from Prometheus and logs from Loki about an app. There are log statements such as:

```
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_1", "ts": 1012}
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_2", "ts": 1008}
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_1", "ts": 1005}
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_1", "ts": 1000}
```

and I have a query to get a list of the "recently active users", using the Grafana Logs panel:

```
{job="my-app"} | json | username != "" | line_format "{{.username}}"
```

I have tried all values of `Deduplication`, and this mostly works fine, except in the (common) case where users are making actions in between each other (as above), then I get logs like this:

```
user_1
user_2
user_1
```

How can I make it so it only shows each user one time?, eg:

```
user_1
user_2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
count by (username) (count_over_time({job="my-app"} | json | username != "" [$__range]))
```

You can show this data using, for example, a pie chart on Grafana. See below how to configure this, using a different log file and a different label ("branch" instead of "username"):

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Didn't think of converting it to a metric. This one mostly works: `sum by (username) (count_over_time{job="my-app"} | json | username != ""[$__range])) > 0`. It's actually nice because I can display this in a pie chart and see which user is most active. For completeness sake, how can I display the information in a list as before? The Table panel with "Instant" selected sort of works but has some extra columns.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "[$__range]" in the answer, I just fixed it. In my test, using the "Instant" option, the unique extra column I see is the "Time" one.

Comment: The time column (which is just the current time since its "Instant") and the "Value #A" which is the series that represents the count. I guess I'm wondering is there a way to make it display just the names in the log panel? Otherwise using it as a pie chart works great, even better than the list honestly.

Comment: Yes, you can show the information in a beautiful pie chart. Important: use "Range" instead of "Instant".